# Extract value from HTML response in jmeter using regular expression

Tags: html, regex, xpath, response, jmeter

I have a problem to extract a value from an HTML response of HTTP request using jmeter.

This source html code to extract from:

```html
<input type="text" name="ifu" size="32" value="1600553" class="champ_texte">
```

I'm using the following regular expression:

```
name of reference = ifu 
regular expression = //input[@type="text"][@name="ifu"][@ size="32"][@value="1600553"][@class="champ_texte"]
```

There is any problem in my expression.
NB: my html response is an response of an Action struts.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you attempt to get/extract as well as what you actually got. Please refine your question.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to parse HTML response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED.
2. Your xpath query should return value you want to extract.
   So to get e.g. 'value' of your 'input' you have to use query like:
   `//input[@type="text"][@name="ifu"][@class="champ_texte"]/@value`
   Extracted value (if any) will be stored in jmeter variable pointed in 'Reference Name' field (${ifu} in your case).
3. You can first test your xpath query using any other tool - Firefox addons at least:

   - [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/)
   - [XPather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpather/)
   - [XPath Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-finder/)

Comment: Beautiful. And I love XPath.

Comment: check my answer xpath is not the right method for this

Comment: ...looks like Jmeter 2.9 which introduced this component as standard one was released "a bit" later.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression could be

```
input type=\"text\" name=\"ifu\" size=\"32\" value=\"(\\d+)\" class=\"champ_texte
```

In more details,

```
String x  ="<input type=\"text\" name=\"ifu\" size=\"32\" value=\"1600553\" class=\"champ_texte\">";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("input type=\"text\" name=\"ifu\" size=\"32\" value=\"(\\d+)\" class=\"champ_texte");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
if (m.find())
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to extract is the value property it is way better to use Css/Jquery Extractor:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor

With config:

- Css/Jquery expression : input[name=ifu]
- Attrbute: value